# SAML handler instantiated on non-SAML authentication requests

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, sustainsys-saml2

I am using the Sustainsys SAML library along with IdentityServer4 for Okta authentication, and have a working setup.  However, I notice that the Saml2Handler is being instantiated for non-SAML authentication requests (even though it does not act on those requests because ModulePath does not match).

It is a concern because I intend to support multiple Okta instances, and it feels wasteful to hit the handler when it is not required. Is this expected behaviour for this SAML library, or for handlers in general?

Currently I create a scheme per-customer, with the handler as an argument. This is set up on first request for the customer rather than in startup.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handler need to check if the incoming request is a response for its endpoint (Acs, Logout or Metadata). As far as I know all handlers work this way.

Comment: Agreed. Handlers will have their `HandleRequestAsync` method called by ASP.NET Core's `AuthenticationMiddleware`. There's not much you can do to stop this unless you start messing with the middleware or scheme stores.

Comment: Thanks both, good to know I'm not missing something obvious.  Because I will be supporting >10 customers, I have switched to using one scheme/handler/Saml2Options, with all IdPs associated with the one instance which seems to be working.